# Unable to send Push Notification to Android User

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to send a Notification to the android device and found a lot of possible solution but nothing help me this regard, because all the solutions are old i think that does not meet the latest firebase requirement.

when i try to send a message everything is fine but when i press the send message button nothing happen i have added the key but nothing help me i just return back to the same point.

[Last Image Where i Added the Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHOn6.png)